# Modifying an array inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, memcached

So I need to modify the array in a memcached key-value pair. I need to remove one of the arrays inside the array. An example of what it looks like:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["username"]=> string(3) "Bob" ["id"]=> string(5) "14537" ["comment"]=> string(4) "cool"} [1]=> array(3) { ["username"]=> string(3) "Tom" ["id"]=> string(5) "14538" ["comment"]=> string(3) "yes"}}
```

If I know the values of username, id, and comment, how can I delete it? The generic queston: How can I delete array 0?

Considering the answer of doing a foreach loop, I tried

```
foreach($memcachedarray as $f){
  if ($f['id'] == '14537'){
    echo key($f);
  }
}
```

But it spits out `username`

Edit- Ok

I searched some more and found I need to do this:

```
foreach($memcachedarray as $key => $f){
if ($f['id'] == '14537'){
echo $key;
}
}
```

That works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Id's are unique across the system then you could use an associative array to store you data then unset the key, otherwise you would want to use a foreach loop to get the array key, then unset that key and recommit your new array back into memcache.